# How to skip existing machines while running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running ansible playbook on a cluster to add new machine. I want this to be run on only to add new machine thinking that there are no old machines existing. I can limit playbook to one machine by using "--limit" but in this case I dont know machine name or ip before creating.

How can I skip existing machines on the cluster while adding new one by ansible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a add_host module if you playbook create a new machine you need catch the public or private IP and relate this with a new group and then use this group in your next play.

Take a look on the next example:

```
- name: Create a sandbox instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    key_name: my_keypair
    instance_type: m1.small
    security_group: my_securitygroup
    image: my_ami_id
    region: us-east-1
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
         group: "{{ security_group }}"
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ image }}"
         wait: true
         region: "{{ region }}"
         vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
         assign_public_ip: yes
      register: ec2
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
      with_items: ec2.instances
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for: host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
      with_items: ec2.instances

- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: launched
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
    - my_awesome_role
    - my_awesome_test
```